# Get variable types inside a Python class

Tags: python, class

For the following example, is there a way to get the type of `a` and `b` as `int` and `string`?

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = "abc"

test_obj = test()
for var in vars(test_obj):
     print type(var) # this just returns string type as expected (see explanation below)
```

Comment: "this just returns string type as expected" Why is this expected?

Comment: `type(var).__name__`

Comment: `vars(test_obj)` is a dictionary and so `var` is just the variable names `'a'` and `'b'`.

Comment: `print(type(getattr(test_obj, var)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate on the values, but you are iterating on the keys of `vars(test_obj)`, when you do that, it works.

Also you can get the name of object using `value.__class__.__name__`

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = "abc"

test_obj = test()

print(vars(test_obj))
#Iterate on values
for value in vars(test_obj).values():
    #Get name of object
    print(value.__class__.__name__)
```

The output will be

```
int
str
```

Comment: I think he wants the string `'int'`, not the object `<class 'int'>`

Comment: Updated, Thanks @Barmar :)

Comment: No worries! People make mistakes :) Glad to help @Lemon ! If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to it :) Please also consider taking a look at stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = "abc"

test_obj = test()

for attr, value in test_obj.__dict__.iteritems():
    print type(value)
```

You access the `attr` as well which will return `a` and `b`. `value` will return the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

One example also printing the type:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = "abc"

test_obj = test()

print(vars(test_obj))

# print(dir(test_obj))

#Iterate on values
for k, v in vars(test_obj).items():
    print('variable is {0}: and variable value is {1}, of type {2}'.format(k,v, type(v)))
```

---

Will provide:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 'abc'}
variable is a: and variable value is 1, of type <class 'int'>
variable is b: and variable value is abc, of type <class 'str'>
```